# PBS: job on two nodes uses memory of only one

Tags: cluster-computing, pbs

I am trying to run a job (python code) on cluster using MPI. There is 63GB of memory available on each node.
When I run it on one node, I specify PBS parameters with (only relevant parameters are listed here):

```
#PBS -l mem=60GB
#PBS -l nodes=node01.cluster:ppn=32
time mpiexec -n 32 python code.py
```

Than works just fine.

Since PBS man page says `mem` is memory per entire job, my parameters when trying to run it on two nodes, are

```
#PBS -l mem=120GB
#PBS -l nodes=node01.cluster:ppn=32+node02.cluster:ppn=32
time mpiexec -n 64 python code.py
```

This doesn't work (`qsub: Job exceeds queue resource limits MSG=cannot satisfy queue max mem requirement`). It fails even if I set `mem=70GB` for example (in case system needs some more memory).
If I set `mem=60GB` when trying to use both nodes, I get

```
=>> PBS: job killed: mem job total xx kb exceeded limit yy kb.
```

I tried it with `pmem` as well (that's `pmem=1875MB`), but no success.

My question is: How can I use entire 120GB of memory?

Answer (score 2):

Torque / PBS ignores the `mem` resource unless the job uses a single node (see [here](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-0-2/Content/topics/2-jobs/requestingRes.htm)):

> Maximum amount of physical memory used by the job. (Ignored on Darwin, Digital Unix, Free BSD, HPUX 11, IRIX, NetBSD, and SunOS. **Also ignored on Linux if number of nodes is not 1.** Not implemented on AIX and HPUX 10.)

You should instead use the `pmem` resource that limits the memory *per job process*. With `ppn=32` you should set `pmem` to 1920MB in order to get 60 GB per node. In that case you should mind that `pmem` does not allow flexible distribution of memory between the processes running on the node the same way `mem` does (since the latter is accounted as an aggregated value while `pmem` applies to each process individually).